# Facebook OAuth2 login using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, spring-security-oauth2, facebook-oauth

I am trying to use the Facebook OAuth Login for my SpringBoot Application.

I followed [this blog](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/) for reference.

All is well till I use Facebook App in Development Mode.

As soon as I turn my App in Live mode. I get below-mentioned Error.

Issue is FB is sending some other JSON format in Dev mode and some other JSON in Live mode.

So getting deserialize error. I want to know how to resolve this. How to implement Custom Parser.

**Please note:** I have already added Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in

```
Facebook Dashboard => FB Login => Setting
```

with HTTPS endpoints like this `https://domain/oauth2/callback/facebook`

Verified same in Redirect URI Validator

Other Configuration info:

application.yml

```
security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            facebook:
              client-id: clientid
              client-secret: secret
              redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
              scope:
                - email
                - public_profile
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ashishontech</groupId>
    <artifactId>assistant</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>assistant</name>
    <description>My Personal Assistant</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>assistant</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>../react-ui</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/../react-ui/build" />
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error Log:

```
2019-11-21 02:31:11.394 ERROR 31626 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: An error occurred reading the OAuth 2.0 Error: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["error"]); nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["error"])
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.java:78) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.java:46) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:75) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:52) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["error"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:245) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(OAuth2ErrorHttpMessageConverter.java:73) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["error"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1442) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1216) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1126) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:527) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 71 common frames omitted

2019-11-21 02:31:11.402 ERROR 31626 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.a.a.s.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint     : Responding with unauthorized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, new update from Facebook is messing up things.

Flow goes like this

We call Facebook for OAuth with redirect URL as param

```
https://domain/oauth2/authorize/facebook?redirect_uri=https://domain/oauth2/redirect
```

Once Login is done, Facebook replies back with code and state

```
https://domain/oauth2/callback/facebook?code=AQBRBkVf-9dzNQwl3UIu8K3lDSBi2J4RVV9mUYxHIr8GGNhDzXo0qWPJDXTxQOFmxQst0yZouYl_8Wow7aqtbdW7rb9gFnJU5gAvq-JCZEG_zeNsULZ2IeCvTRO3sHw36cmKKXD6MNGPnx6ukoLozXRmzEfAtnadqVP1go-PkqOHttSlfvBzPIQjfwILwpGn1qgEpEQ0zWR4rxw6F13HvO4-jSECKy6VYVT8jZlknzxsWJlblzkBTr0SLxZ3SE5A_JmcwmxqROtAdJypzQd6FO3rkMOENbhICwHy3Cpl49xobVDzMbSo6YhfnDjTxe1mT1TCSOK-6Wac2xbOjqOfaecZwHg9dBXaw3MGBw9ybqHmQA&state=jodmAOiDgMBnqOfOjifiEkd5K2_0vTu3QaczcKpQh9o%3D
```

We use this `code` and `state` to get `AUTH_TOKEN`. Here I was facing a problem.

Even though I have configured `redirect_url` as `https` facebook was attaching with `http`, which was throwing an exception. For other Domains its http only and working fine like for Github and Google.

As per there latest App update, all Live Apps redirect calls must be `https`.

**To resolved this**

I had to modify my security configuration to add `tokenEndpoint` where I will convert `http` to `https` for Facebook redirect URL

Security Configuration:

```
.redirectionEndpoint()
    .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
    .and()
.tokenEndpoint()
    .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
    .and()
.userInfoEndpoint()
    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
```

accessTokenResponseClient:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient(){
    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = 
      new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient(); 
    accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(new CustomRequestEntityConverter()); 
    return accessTokenResponseClient;
}
```

CustomRequestEntityConverter:

```
public class CustomRequestEntityConverter implements Converter<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest, RequestEntity<?>> {

  private OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter defaultConverter;

  public CustomRequestEntityConverter() {
      defaultConverter = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter();
  }

  @Override
  public RequestEntity<?> convert(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest req) {
      RequestEntity<?> entity = defaultConverter.convert(req);
      MultiValueMap<String, String> params =  (MultiValueMap<String, String>) entity.getBody();
      String url = params.getFirst("redirect_uri");
      if(url.contains("facebook")){
          url = url.replace("http", "https");
      }
      params.set("redirect_uri", url);
      log.info("Callback Request Parameters: "+params.toSingleValueMap().toString());
      return new RequestEntity<>(params, entity.getHeaders(), 
        entity.getMethod(), entity.getUrl());
  }

}
```